# Why is my git terminal stuck on a master branch?

Tags: git, github

Am hoping to get some answers to my git problem here. My terminal for whatever reason is stuck on this master branch that I didn't even initiate. Why is that? I've uninstalled and reinstalled git several times, but it's still showing the same. [image]

Comment: What does `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` output?

Comment: Don't post images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Uninstalling/reinstalling git would not be relevant.  It looks like your prompt is displaying the current branch, probably of the working directory you are in.  Change the branch.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling Git won't delete all your repos, and it looks like you did `git init` in your home directory, so Git's all set up to track absolutely everything. `rm -rf .git` to remove the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you initialize a git repo, you drop a hidden `.git` file inside the directory you put it in. It's possible your dropped a repo in a folder from a while ago and still have an existing `.git` file. You could run an `ls -lisah` or `dir /a:h` (or just `.g` + <kbd>tab</kbd> complete) in order to check and then you can delete the `.git` file.